# Codeigniter + Ion Auth - Are "groups" relevant in my case?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, ion-auth

I am currently using CodeIgniter with a homemade authentification system but I would like to switch to Ion Auth.

Every user's account is attached to a company's account. A company's account can have > 1 user's account attached.

Example:

```
- Company 1 => User id 1, user id 2, user id 3
- Company 2 => User id 4
```

etc

Is the "groups" function in Ion Auth relevant for storing this company data? I can, therefore, use the "users" table in order to save my users and the "groups" table in order to save companies. Is this choice relevant?

Comment: This is an opinion based question, therefore off-topic for SO.  However, I don't think your proposal fits the intended usage of "groups".  You should have two groups... one for "company users" and another for your "administrators".  Think of groups as a way to define users by their privileges.

Comment: As stated your question is somewhat opinion based. If your intent is to use the company info to determine what privileges the user has then yes it could be relevant. Contrary to the opinion of @Sparky "groups" can be useful beyond a simple user vs admin scenario.

Comment: @DFriend, where exactly did I say "groups" was not useful beyond user vs. admin?

Comment: @Sparky, when you said "You should have two groups...one for "company users" and another for your "administrators"."  seems fairly explicit to me.

Comment: @DFriend, I think you're reading too much into it.  I gave a simple example that was most relevant to the OP's proposal and stated as such.  Since comments are not for discussion, I'll leave it there.

Comment: I'm looking for ideas to better find a relevant system for my problem. But yes, you're right, groups are relevant for like "Admin" / "Members" / "VIP" etc...

Comment: Ion Auth only for user login... totally separate from keeping track of users within your company table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use groups to define the company and create additional fields in the users table (or separate) for the company data;

Then you can use the below to check if the user is in a particular company/group

```
if ($this->ion_auth->in_group("company1")){
    //your company stuff here
}
```